# Recent activity in profile versus the StackExchange icon?

Tags: feature-request, questions, recent-activity

It seems like with the addition of the new StackExchange menu in the upper left corner, I now receive notifications in two separate places. I think I understand why.. site specific notifications like on StackOverflow and notifications across various StackExchange sites.

However, it seems that when I have notifications in both places, they are not CLEARED in both places.

For example:

1. I have 7 StackOverflow notifications while browsing. (orangered envelope and StackExchange icon)
2. I click my orangered envelope
3. System clears orangered envelope
4. System does **NOT** clear StackExchange notifications (the same notifications I view in my StackOverflow profile)

If I view the notifications in either place, shouldn't they be cleared in both places?

Comment: I asked this question earlier, although not with as much clarity, and was kind of given a hard time about it...glad to see you are having a better time...+1!

Comment: @studiohack: Sorry to hear that! I thought for sure someone would have already asked this but couldn't find it. Hopefully someone has an answer!